# Returning a value from lambda inside a method

Tags: java, android

I'm completely lost here.
I have a method like this

```
String foo(String param) {
    seechOutput(params, () -> {
    // Callback after the task is performed!
    // Speech output task.
       speechInput(params, (result) -> {
           // Some calculations.
           // Now return result to the caller function of foo.
       });
    });
}
```

I tried while() loop outside of lambda but that didn't worked.

how to return the value?

Is there is any better design approach?

EDIT: Here is the Original Code.

```
        String getNumberFromName(String name) {
            AtomicReference<String> finalResult = new AtomicReference<>("");
            int i = 1;
            StringBuilder toSpeak = new StringBuilder("There are multiple contacts, Which one you wanted to call? ");
            for (String s : hs.keySet()) {
                toSpeak.append(i).append(". ").append(s).append(", ");
                ++i;
            }
            System.out.println(toSpeak);    
            audioOutput.speak(String.valueOf(toSpeak), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, "multiple1", () -> {
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    mSpeechInput.startListening((str) -> {
                        finalResult.set(str);
                    });
                });

            });
            return finalResult.get();
        }
```

Comment: you should hold a variable and assign it on the lambda

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher How? An Example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `RxJava`, you can go with:

```
Single<String> speechResult(String param) {
    return Single.fromEmitter(emitter -> {
        speechOutput(params, () -> {
            speechInput(params, (result) -> {
                 emitter.onSuccess(result);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

With usage:

```
speechResult("").subscribe(result -> /* Do something with result */);
```

You could probably do this with a `Future` as well, although you'd need to block in the method until it returns.

Or, you can define your own callback:

```
void speechResult(String param, Consumer<String> onComplete) {
    speechOutput(params, () -> {
        speechInput(params, (result) -> {
            onComplete.accept(result);
        });
    });
}
```

With usage:

```
speechResult("", result -> /* Do something with result*/);
```

Comment: Yeah! Slowly getting deep into callback hell.

Comment: You don't have many other options for asynchronous work, unfortunately. You could block until you get the result, but you'd need to ensure this was done off the UI thread anyway as your app would probably crash with an ANR.

Comment: You could switch to Kotlin (and use coroutines)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
String foo(String param) {
    String finalResult = "";
    seechOutput(params, () -> {
        // Callback after the task is performed!
        // Speech output task.
        speechInput(params, (result) -> {
            // Some calculations.
            // Now return result to the caller function of foo.
            finalResult = result;
        });
    });
    return finalResult;
}
```

> If your function is synchronous then this will work perfectly. If you're doing some asynchronous operations, then the `finalResult` will be empty.

If it's asynchronous do it like this

```
interface AsyncCallback {

void catchResult(String result)
}
```

Edit your method like

```
foo(String param,AsyncCallback callback) {
// your code here  
speechInput(params, (result) -> {
        //here use the method
       callback.catchResult(result)
   });
}
```

Use it like

```
foo("params", new AsyncCallback() {

@Override
public void catchResult(String number) {
// result here
}
});
```

Comment: This depends on whether or not the task is synchronous - otherwise the function will just return an empty string immediately

Comment: @PPartisan definitely

Comment: it looks asynchronous with speechoutput.

Comment: @PPartisan The exact Problem Function is just returning an Empty String :-(